# How do i modify this smarty template so it just uses one <ul> for all the categories?

Tags: javascript, html, css, smarty, prestashop

This is the smarty template of a module I am using in prestashop. It uses a `<ul>` for every category.. and each item for that category is in a `<li>`.

```
{assign var=zItem value=0}
{if isset($isian) AND $isian}
        {foreach from=$isian item=cat name=productCat}
    {assign var=zItem value=$zItem+1}

        {$products=$cat.produk}
        {if isset($products) && $products}
                    {counter name=active_ul assign=active_ul}
                    {include file="$style" class='homefeatured tab-pane' id='prodcat' active=$active_ul}
                    {/if}


     {/foreach}
    {else}
            <p>{l s='No featured products' mod='prodcat'}</p>
    {/if}
```

The Items are already displayed correctly which is inline-block float left. I want the third item in the picture to be right next to the 2nd item but they aren't because they belong to different `<ul>`s
[image]

How do i edit the smarty template so that it just puts all items in one `<ul>` regardless of what category they belong to?

Or not use `<ul> and <li>` at all.. just divs.. as long as the third item is next to the 2nd item dynamically.

Below is the tab.tpl file if that helps =/

```
{*
* 2007-2014 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2014 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
    *}am using in prestashop. It uses a <ul> for every category.. and each item for that category is in a <li>.

{assign var=z
<li><a class="homefeatured">{l s='By Category' mod='prodcat'}</a></li>
```

Comment: Without seeing the included template file this is just guessing, but I'd assume that you have to move the `<ul>` out of the included template file and add it out of the loop in the shown template. Of course this will affect all files where this template is included.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I want to do but I dunno how to code Smarty Template. =/ Do you know how??

Comment: ugly code, more than one `<ul>` have same ID, but let's try. I need code that contain "$style" file, as I remember you have something like `tab.tpl`, show me it please

Comment: there is mess in the code, check it please, I need original content of file

Comment: Here :D
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8SkndypMGURWXRmd3NLRlhhT00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: nothing in this file. Pack please whole module folder and give me archive

Comment: @SergiiP Sorry. I can't I'd get into a lot of trouble if I do that. Our module is purchased. Anyways. My coworker is incharge of this task now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added this script.

```
var cnt = $(".homefeatured").contents();
$(".homefeatured").replaceWith(cnt);

$('.last-in-line, .last-item-of-tablet-line ,.first-item-of-mobile-line').removeClass('.last-in-line, .last-item-of-tablet-line ,.first-item-of-mobile-line');

$('.last-in-line, .last-item-of-tablet-line ,.first-item-of-mobile-line').removeClass('last-in-line last-item-of-tablet-line first-item-of-mobile-line');

$('.last-mobile-line').removeClass('last-mobile-line');

$('.last-item-of-mobile-line').removeClass('last-item-of-mobile-line');

$('.first-in-line , .first-item-of-tablet-line').removeClass('first-in-line first-item-of-tablet-line');

$('.last-line').removeClass('last-line');

$('.ajax_block_product').wrapAll('<ul id="prodcat" class="product_list grid row homefeatured tab-pane" />');
```